# Counter weight rod

Tags: telescope, amateur-observing

Someone gave me an Orion StarBlast 4.5 EQ, and with it everything but the counterweight shaft. Because of this, the telescope is hard to use. It flops around quite a bit making viewing of objects difficult. Where can I buy just that part? I looked it up and all I could find is an "upgrade" to the rod for $70.

Comment: "what does the rod to gold metal mean?" Have you contacted customer services at orion telescopes? What did they say?

Answer (score 1):

I have that same telescope in my collection! It served me well and I hope it will do the same for you.

This counterweight is not the one which comes with the telescope, but it should function much the same$-$it is $30.00, and you can find it [here](http://www.highpointscientific.com/skywatcher-counterweight-kit-star-adventurer-s20540?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cse&utm_term=SKY-S20540&gclid=Cj0KCQjwqvvLBRDIARIsAMYuvBF12HwLruQVZtkUV6DOeU8aO0J1mvXcTIzXlJcCHW7rbSia3jy7GUIaAib1EALw_wcB).

Clear skies!